# Localize several storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a project which is relatively big, for such reason I use several storyboards. The thing is, I have not find the way to localize several storyboards in xcode. The options I see when using `Base Internationalization` are only related to my `Main.storyboard` and the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` files.

My app should be in english and spanish, those are the requirements. I have searched and searched but have not found the way to have `.strings` (english and spanish) for every storyboard, except the Main.

My storyboards are located in disk (and project structure) like this:

```
General_UI_Folder
   Main.storyboard (with its .strings)
   LaunchScreen.storyboard (with its .strings)
   Subfolder1
     ...several .storyboards
   Subfolder2
     ...several .storyboards
```

I'm using Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

I would appreciate any help, since I'm somehow new to iOS development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 choices.

1) You localize each storyboard, using the storyboard localization system where it creates "substoryboards", 1 per language, where you change the value of labels, and other components, straight into the storyboards themselves.

You have to use this option:

[image]

2) Use the Localizable.strings files and update your view in every `viewDidLoad` method of your controllers.

Comment: Thanks a lot benzarz. Option one was exactly what I was looking for, option 2 what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Glad I could help!